# Why is this ice cloudy at the center and has a transparent layer?

Tags: experimental-physics, home-experiment, ice

[image: The ice is cloudy at the center and has a transparent layer]

This fell at my place during a hailstorm. I can not figure it out why it is like this.

Answer (score 1):

Water freezes from the outside in, as the outside is exposed to the coldest temperature. Therefore any impurities as pushed inwards as the water crystallises. These impurities are then compacted in the centre of the ice, making it cloudy as seen in your photo.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail or give some link on how this freezing happens

Comment: Are you sure this is the right answer? I was under the impression it was micro-cracks due to stresses from expanding ice.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I think the two ideas are linked; slowly freezing the ice would mean less micro-cracks, yet this would be pointless if you had water with a lot of impurities.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice#Formation here in the first paragraph it explains that this effect is indeed due to impurities, such as soil particles or even small air bubbles.